# How can I send the contents of a table with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Need help on how to send the contents of a table with retrofit.

I have a database under ormlite in which I save the entries of my Post class.
What I want is to be able to send all the data contained in the table with retrofit to my web service.
For now with the code below it does not work.
Can someone help me take off?

```
public class Post {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    String title;
    @DatabaseField
    String body;

    Post(){
    //empty constructor
    }

    public Post(int id, String title, String body) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

//Service

```
public interface ApiService{

    @POST("articles")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> myPosts(@Body List<Post> post);
}
```

//Calling

```
Post post = new Post();

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.validBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postAllPosts(post);
            }
        });

public void postAllPosts(List<Post> getPost){

        //  dialog();
        // JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, );
        Call<Post> call = service.myPosts(getPost);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();

                Log.i(TAG, "Status Code: " + statusCode);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + t.toString());
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: My Solution
`private List<Post> mListPost = new ArrayList<>();`
//in activity onCreate 
`mList = Post.findAll(mContext);`
//then finally my call
`public void postAllPosts(){
    Call<Post> call = service.myPosts(mListPost);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
       ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Gson to create json files that you can send via body to the server. Gson can translate any object, like your list.

https://github.com/google/gson